# Updating Django Form Choice Field dynamically from Enum

Tags: python, django, django-models, enums, django-forms

I am trying to update choices for Choice Field in Django dynamically.

I have enums called DOMAINS and related SUBDOMAINS for each DOMAIN as a Hash.

```
 DOMAINS = (
    (CHE_DOMAIN, 'Chemistry'),
    (CS_DOMAIN, 'Computer Science'),
 )
 SUBDOMAINS = {
    CHE_DOMAIN: (
        ('CHE-CCHE', 'Computational Chemistry'),
        (OTHER_DOMAINS, 'Others'),
    ),
    CS_DOMAIN: (
        ('CS-ALG', 'Algorithms'),
        ('CS-AI', 'Artifical Intelligence'),
        ('CS-CRYP', 'Cryptography'),
    ),
   }
```

So if a user selects CS_DOMAIN my sub domain has to get populated with sub domains under CS.

I have my model like this

```
domain = models.CharField(max_length=MyEnums.DOMAIN_CODE_LEN,
                                    choices=MyEnums.DOMAINS,
                                    blank=False, null=False, default=MyEnums.OTHER_DOMAINS)
subdomain1 = models.CharField(max_length=MyEnums.DOMAIN_CODE_LEN,
                              blank=False, null=False, default=MyEnums.OTHER_DOMAINS)
subdomain2 = models.CharField(max_length=MyEnums.DOMAIN_CODE_LEN,
                              blank=False, null=False, default=MyEnums.OTHER_DOMAINS)
```

I was not knowing how to populate this dynamically in my form. However when I tried to hard code for experimenting..

```
class ResearchAreasForm(forms.ModelForm):
    subdomain1 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=MyEnums.SUBDOMAINS['CHE'])
    subdomain2 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=MyEnums.SUBDOMAINS['CHE'])
```

It is giving this error.

> Exception Type:   ValueError
>
> Exception Value:
>   need more than 1 value to unpack

Any suggestions on how I can update the form choice values dynamically and the reason why the error is coming with my hard code? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have an actual traceback?  If so, please post it.

Comment: Are you using the new [Enum](http://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) type?  (backport [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34))

Comment: No.. Anyways I could solve it. I just tried pasting both the lines in the form shown, inside init method and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: If you can, please post your solution as an answer, and then accept it in two days.